# scanbd on Raspberry pi using ScanSnap ix500

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, scanning, sane

I have not been able to successfully use this. When I run scanbd -f I get the following errors.

scanbd: SANE_CONFIG_DIR not set

scanbd: Not Primary Owner (-1)

scanbd: Name Eror (Connection ":1.189" is not allowed to own the service "de.kmux.scanbd.server" due to security policies in the configuration file)

scanbd: trigger action for scan for device fujitsu:ScanSncap ix500:277299 with script /home/pi/scripts.sh